# Use variable data from one form for another in v.net

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program to calculate payrolls for employees. What I need to know is how to get payroll information from variables from one form to another.

The form I need the variable data from is called Timesheet and the form I need the data for is called PayRoll.

When I use the following code:

```
  lblName.Text = TimeSheet.EmpName
```

I get the error that EmpName is not a member of EmployeeInfo.Timesheet (the project file the Timesheet is located) after I generated a class for it.

Any ideas to link these forms?

Comment: You have to create `public` properties in your class.

Comment: You should post some code where you call the line above. Also, please explain your architecture. Are you showing the forms modally or do you have an MDI structure?

Comment: This is the code I have in TimeSheet  `Public EmpName As String
    Public Supervisor As String
    Public Period As String
    Public Client1 As String
    Public Client2 As String
    Public Contract1 As String
    Public Contract2 As String
    Public Project1 As String
    Public Project2 As String
    Public BillLevel As String
    Public BillLevel2 As String
    Public TotalHours As Double
    Public PTO As Double

    Private Sub frmPayroll_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        EmpName = txtEmpName.Text
        Supervisor = txtSupervisor.Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be anything wrong with that as long as you are calling the TimeSheet form from the PayRoll form and as long as you have instanciated and retained an instance of that form.

I would expect to see something like:

```
Dim ts as New TimeSheet
ts.ShowDialog()
' Do whatever you need in the timesheet form to set it.
lblName.Text = ts.EmpName
```

One thing to note is if you call the Dispose() method you will loose your property.

More information on your problem might be more helpful if this does not answer your question.